# What is the trust model in bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, trust, websites

Bitcoin.org seems to be hacked.

1. How can it be reclaimed, especially since the listed address is receiving a lot of funding?
2. More importantly, what is the procedure for a new user in establishing trust for bitcoin-related-software(keys for core client, websites etc.)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As per the discussion on answers, especially [Murch's](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/115690/35931), the answer seems to be there is no trust model. Bitcoin users MUST be able to understand the code they are running, otherwise are insecure.

Answer (score 1):

As @1440000bytes already mentioned, Bitcoin doesn't have an official website, although there are numerous sites run by various individuals. Some projects have their own websites such as [bitcoincore.org](https://bitcoincore.org).

The final version of the release will be tagged and signed by one of the maintainers whose keys are listed in [bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys). Release candidates are then built by many volunteers from the source code in parallel in our deterministic build process to compare that they create the same binary. The builders' keys, attestations, and instructions how to verify them are found in the [release process document](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-process.md#verify-other-builders-signatures-to-your-own-optional). You can find a description of the process here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/110517/5406

Older versions of Bitcoin Core releases were signed with the [release signing key](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7fcf53f7b4524572d1d0c9a5fdc388e87eb02416/contrib/verifybinaries/README.md).

If so inclined, you will find that many of these keys, especially the release signing key, are attested to by other  Bitcoin Core contributors. If this does not suffice, you could put the key into your web of trust by attending a key signing party at a Bitcoin conference.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this as an answer if you could please edit it to say the model is 'web of trust facilitated by in-person key signing ceremony' part only, since the rest of the answer highlights the issue with third party websites. Also, if you could please add how/if this web of trust leads back to Satoshi.

Comment: While Satoshi had a pgp key on one of his profiles, Satoshi never publicly signed anything except his Bitcoin transactions. I don't agree that my answer summarizes to “it boils down to web of trust”. Rather, most people appear to trust that the release process facilitated per the GitHub repository is not compromised. If you feel that you have a better answer, please write your own.

Answer (score 0):

> How can it be reclaimed, especially since the listed address is receiving a lot of funding?

**bitcoin.org** domain and website is now owned by [Cobra](https://twitter.com/CobraBitcoin/). I don't see a point in trying to reclaim it, however you will have to discuss it with the website owner if trying to get access ethically.

There is no official website for bitcoin and this is good for decentralization although creates some confusion for newbies and journalists.

> More importantly, what is the procedure for a new user in establishing trust for bitcoin related software(keys for core client, websites etc.)?

Users should download bitcoin core from **bitcoincore.org** and other projects have their own website or repositories.

This was even shared by Pieter Wuille in an email when one user could not get the binary from bitcoin.org: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-October/019568.html

Comment: Thanks for info but does not answer the question. How is trust established?

Comment: TBH everyone has to figure out. My background was darknet and I knew whats happening. Know some programming languages and tried contributing to bitcoin core, I could confirm bitcoin.org is owned by cobra, bitcoin.com is owned by Roger Ver but **Bitcoin** is different where all devs compete, users run nodes, exchanges identify as BTC, merchants know it is bitcoin and everyone I knew could see who is trying to scam from forks.

Comment: Sorry, the answer to use darknet & somehow an individual will figure it out doesn't make sense. Specifically how can cryptography be used to establish a chain of trust?

Comment: Apart from a non-answer, your answer is also making a comment about "confusion for newbies & journalists", can you please clarify? (If it helps I have been a bitcoin user since 2010 and an experienced cryptography user)

Comment: I just meant some users consider bitcoin.org or bitcoin.com as official bitcoin website and use bitcoin based on binaries available on those websites.