# Bitcoin Core file with the signing keys was removed from repo. How is the process supposed to be now?

Tags: bitcoin-core, signature, validation, pgp

Yesterday this [PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/296e88225096125b08665b97715c5b8ebb1d28ec) was merged into the Bitcoin repository, and the process described at https://bitcoincore.org/download mentions that to validate the source code, you must download the txt file with some of the devs' signatures.

Now that process is no longer valid because the file was deleted.
What will be the process to validate the source code download from now on?

I reviewed another answer like [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50185/how-to-verify-bitcoin-core-release-signing-keys/50186#50186) but I can find any related to my question.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of fetching the keys from keyservers by fingerprint, you can now get the keys actually used from https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/tree/main/builder-keys. This repository contains all of the guix attestations for Bitcoin Core releases, so it makes sense that the same repo should contain the listing of keys.

Comment: And have some plans to update this information on bitcoincore.org?
Because right now, the process is "broken" if you try to follow the steps indicated on the web.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, the website will be updated.