# How do I verify Bitcoin Core’s integrity?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, verification, pgp

I'm trying to verify release signatures, but I have no idea how. It says to open a terminal window, and every time I do, I have no idea what to type. I’m using Windows. I downloaded the Bitcoin Core and I am basically stuck on what to do after that. Can someone walk me through how to finish set up and use PGP?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50185/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116649/5406